# iOS Simulator App not launching

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator

I am trying to run an app that someone developed and wanted me to test.  The app was working fine for a long time by me placing the folder with long string of number and letters (e.g. 75E3C879-F608-45C6-A8AD-253A37FF92B8) into ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications.  The simulator stopped working when I was trying to copy some new files into the same folder name without deleting the previous folder so OS X automatically appended "-1" to the end of the folder name (e.g. 75E3C879-F608-45C6-A8AD-253A37FF92B8 & 75E3C879-F608-45C6-A8AD-253A37FF92B8-1).  When I launched the simulator with both those folders in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications the simulator starts up and I see the app but when I click on it the screen flashes and then it does nothing.  I have a feeling that because I had two folders with the same app it is causing some kind of error.

I am running xcode 4.2.1 on lion and have actually uninstalled and reinstalled xcode several times hoping it would clear out anything cached but have no luck so far.  I don't have the actual source code so I can't create a new build myself.  I've looked into all the different files that can possibly contain any reference to the app (e.g. ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist, ~/Library/Caches/comapple.iphonesimulator, ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator, ~/Library/Save Application State/com.apple.iphonesimulaotr.savedState) and manually deleted them and still no luck.

I created a new user in OS X and ran the the app in the simulator without any issues so I can rule out that the build is bad.  I really believe that the issue is some cache or preference tied to my user.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a security violation, you are trying to modify the sandbox of an application from outside the application.  Even if you get it to work, it should be considered a bug, because this kind of behavior doesn't make sense to allow.  Can you imagine the fun time black hats would have modifying the sandbox files of an existing app to include malicious code, or modify databases?  Only the app itself is allowed to modify those files.

Comment: I'm not trying to modify any code in the files.  I just want to show the app in the simulator over a web meeting.  It is not possible to show an app from the iPad over webex.

Comment: Oh!  You mean you are trying to fully replace one folder with another?  In that case move the old one out first, then move the new one in.  Don't rename it because it needs to match the expected identifier.

Comment: @borrden I did replace the folder with the newer files and left the name of the folder the same but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The other user was just a test user.  I will use it as a work around but I still would like to know why it's not working for my primary user account.